# Can a shop in the Netherlands force you to buy clothes if you take a photo?

Tags: legal, netherlands, shopping, photography

I've just been in a shop in Amsterdam which had a sign saying:

> No pictures allowed and specially not when wearing our garments!!!
>
> If we see you making pictures anyway, you will have to buy them by law!!

To my British sensibilities, it seems highly unlikely such a law would actually exist anywhere in Europe, as despite what cultural variation there is, this seems a bit extreme—it's one thing to require you to buy something you break, as is a done thing in some places, but it's a whole different class when you've not deprived the store of anything of value.

Can they oblige you to buy something in such a way? If you they try to, what should you do?

Comment: Didn't you know that having a piece of cardboard and a permanent marker enables people to make up laws at their own convenience? This can be very useful at times.

Comment: My Dutch sensibilities are exactly the same :-)

Comment: If you break something, they should charge it to their or your insurance, not to your purse.

Comment: @Willeke Ah, in the UK in principle they can make you pay (though doing so by legal means is exceptionally rare).

Comment: In all the years that I've lived in The Netherlands I've never heard of such a law. Are you sure that this is not a misinterpretation or wrong translation? Also it is normal for some stores to ban people from using cameras, cell phones or recording devices on their property, this rule even existed in my fathers store. Although the *"If we see you making pictures anyway, you will have to buy them by law!!"* rule is absolutely absurd and I don't think that law actually exists, as anything is possible so make sure you research this law and if it exists before taking any action (if you do).

Comment: You should have taken a picture of the sign.

Comment: @phoog that was EXACTLY what I was thinking. Also I was wondering if it is illegal to lie about laws or make them up because if it is you could try to do a good thing and warn them about their mistake.

Comment: @Willeke if the customer is liable for damaging the store's property then it is up to the customer to have, and seek reimbursement from, an insurer. I imagine most do not. If the store has its own insurance, it's possible that the insurer would take care of collecting from the customer or the customer's insurer, but the liability still lies with the customer, not the insurer.

Comment: @phoog but then he'd have to buy the sign...

Comment: Sounds counterproductive. If I were the owner of that clothes shop, I'd ask them to share their pictures on social media, and mention where the pic was taken. Free advertising!

Comment: @Mango exactly what the sign said,  mistakes and all; there was no Dutch, either!

Comment: If you're in a change room trying on clothes and you take a picture of yourself, just don't tell any employees - if they see you taking a picture in the change room, that means **they're spying on you in the change room!** which is probably against a real law. (Unless... it's a lingerie  / underwear store, and there's no trying on clothes & they can't sell an item after it's been worn, but there shouldn't be change rooms then) @Mango I think lying is legal almost everywhere, the cops love to do it in some places. Actually, it usually *is illegal to lie to a cop,* just not vice versa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I was rather expecting this to be the case! Still, a bit extreme piece of fake law!

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit for http://law.stackexchange.com.  While it is a question that in principle could be of interest to travelers, it seems like legal experts would be more able to answer it authoritatively than travel experts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about travel.

Comment: If the sign is solely in English, it sounds like it's aimed at travellers, which is a good sign of it being travel-related.

Comment: Depending on the type of store, the sign might be aimed at either shoppers who take pictures of merchandise only to buy it (slightly) cheaper online, or tourists taking pictures of themselves wearing funny clothing without any intention of buying it. Considering that the sign was in English only, the latter seems likeliest. Which makes sense from the shop owner's perspective, they will want to sell clothes instead of people dressing up and taking pictures. Still not legal, though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Being Dutch, I have never heard of such law.
I also doubt there is a law that would cover this, I would take it as a try to intimidate you. But also as a 'please really, really do not do this.'

If caught out after you made the picture and before you had seen the sign, I would let them try to sue you.
But if seeing the sign before you take the picture, do not take one.

If the designs in the shop are unique, they have the right to protect their copy-right, but that would go for pictures of the clothing without it being worn.
I would not let me be bullied into buying their clothing, but I would also not take photos of me wearing stock unless I have approval of shop staff.

Added:
Taking the photo is not breaking the copy-right laws, using the information from the photo might be. But that breaking of the copy-right laws can also happen after you have bought the item, much easier even. So I doubt the judge (if it came to a court case) would accept it as reason to be forced to buy the item.

I am Dutch, I am not a lawyer but I am pretty much aware of customer rights.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of the copyright side of this, given the variation in copyright law as pertains to fashion.

Comment: taking photos for commercial purposes (or playing runway model in the store, much the same) may well pass for trespassing. They no doubt want to avoid hordes of schoolkids coming in and playing in the store, messing up the items on display, and then posting photos of themselves doing so on facebook.

Comment: If you hadn't seen the sign, and they get annoyed, you could offer to delete the photo.  That's the most likely way for you to keep them happy by respecting their wishes, assuming that you want to do that.

Comment: I saw a really impressive chocolate store display in Germany a few years ago and snapped a photo with a little point-and-shoot camera- from the 'public' area outside the shop. The proprietress came out and rather sternly insisted I delete the photo. I suspect European sensibilities are a bit different from North American ones when it comes to snapping photos. A situation that is similar is in trade shows where unauthorized photos are almost always prohibited- in North America, in Asia and in Europe (enforcement, however, seems a bit variable). It's a lost cause these day with cell phones.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany There is no such thing as "European sensibilities": Europe is a large number of separate countries with distinct cultural norms and some Europeans have very different sensibilities from others. I don't know what the law says in Germany, but in the UK, taking a photograph of a shop display from the public street is, legally, no problem at all; from the "public" part of a mall, it would be up to the owners of the mall, not the shop, to decide policy. Similarly, trade shows are private venues so they can impose whatever rules they want about photography.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Are we really talking about how a customer can make an annoyed vendor happy? Shouldn't this work the other way round? ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:  If you accidentally offended someone, you'll probably feel better in the long run if you find a solution that keeps everyone happy, regardless of who they are.  Also note that in this case they're probably not considering people as customers if they think they're only  coming in to take pictures without buying anything.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm not convinced this can work when dealing with people who want to sell something, as they then have an incentive to pretend being annoyed in order to make the customer buy more. In other cases, I fully agree with your strategy. As for the described case, of course, the vendor may, at their own risk, assume that the photographing person is not going to buy anything in that store, neither now nor in the future. The vendor is then free to leave a lasting impression and thereby turn their assumption into a self-fulfilling prophecy :)

Comment: There is [no copyright on fashion](http://www.wipo.int/wipo_magazine/en/2014/03/article_0007.html). That's why high-end designers rely on trademark instead (e.g. "LV" and Prada logos, or red soles on Louboutin shoes).

Comment: In Poland, there is specific law against such things, and it looks like it was create to explicitly stop shop owners from "you are using it as if it was yours, so pay" approach. So if it needed to be stopped, then it used to be at least semi-legal. Maybe something like that happened in your country now?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: the sign seems to be about people trying on clothes, taking pictures of them, then not buying them. I.e., not customers.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: People who decide against buying a particular item at a particular occasion (possibly even based upon a photo) can become or already be customers nonetheless. My point is that by the described behaviour, the vendor is greatly reducing any chance that the person wants to be a customer in that store.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I have seen signs in the U.S. telling people not to take photos while wearing store-owned merchandise.  I would guess that before posting such signage, the stores may have had a sufficient influx of people  trying on merchandise for the sole purpose of taking photos that it detracted from the business of selling clothes to people seeking to buy it.  That having been said, I would wonder if such people were so numerous as to pose a problem, the store might benefit from selling a souvenir-photo service in addition to their merchandise.